# Debug Node, what is keeping it running?

Tags: node.js

I have a script written for Node.Js that collects a load of data, processes it, saves and then finishes.  Unfortunately something I've done that is preventing the script from finishing and node closing, instead it remains open.

I'll probably just work my way through the changes I've made and try to track it down, but... Is there an easy way to debug node and find out what code / event / callback / connection or whatever, that it's waiting for?

I've had a look at node-inspector but I couldn't figure out how to track down anything keeping it open.  Any advice?

Comment: Appeared to be a module for logentries not closing properly.  Haven't marked this as answered since it'd still be useful to know a way to find out what node is waiting around for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run your node.js program using [wtfnode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode) or add `require('wtfnode').init();` on the first line or your program.  It will then print the list of all the things keeping node open when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to kill the process.

Comment: I'm trying to use this in my mocha tests, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything else I have to do to make this work with mocha?

Answer (score 4):

When I've had this happen it's most often something like mongodb, amqp etc. That is database connections, network connections. Make sure you close those once you're done processing.

I guess you could use `lsof -p <PID>` and see what that says. I can see both mongodb and amqp in there.

Answer (score 3):

At the point where you expect it to close add

```
console.log(process._getActiveHandles());
```

You can also add a handler

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => console.log(process._getActiveHandles()) );
```

So if node does not close correctly, Ctrl + C will tell you why.

Comment: BTW adding this answer because wftnode did not work for me due to the fact it prevents exit handlers from running.  Kudos to myndzi for the technique. I would recomment wtfnode if you dont have exit handlers.